# Use value for dynamic xpath on xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

my question/target is: How can I generate the content in firstPart?

(My compiler can't dynamic evaluate()-functions and is based on XSLT 1.0 (VB.NET). I only want to use board tools.)

The output should consist of 2 main parts. In the first part I want to iterate over the person and choose the one which was described in /root/choosePerson. The second part consist of all the persons, which are in /root/person.

Now it's getting difficult: In the output I should get an ID-Attribute, referring to the Person in firstPart. The secondPart has a slight other algorithm, which doesn't show the birthdate.

input.xml:

```
<root>
<person> <name>bart</name> <gender>m</gender> <birth>01.01.2016</birth> </person>
<person> <name>lisa</name> <gender>w</gender> <birth>01.01.2015</birth> </person>
<person> <name>homer</name> <gender>m</gender> <birth>01.01.2014</birth> </person>
<choosePerson>choose person: 1</choosePerson><!-- it really consist of string and a number -->
<root>
```

output.xml:

```
<MyNewRoot>
<firstPart>
<person id="1" gender="m"><name>bart</name> <birth>01.01.2016</birth> </person>
<firstPart>
<secondPart>
<person id="1" gender="m"> <name>bart</name>  </person>
<person id="2" gender="w"> <name>lisa</name>  </person>
<person id="3" gender="m"> <name>homer</name>  </person>
</secondPart>
<MyNewRoot>
```

What whould I do? I could start with the second part at first:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<firstPart>

<firstPart>
<secondPart>
<xsl:apply-templates select="//root/person"/>
</secondPart>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//root/person"">
<!-- incomplete code (for the sake of clarity), but here I copy the values and create an id through the position() method -->
</xsl:template>
```

I know dynamic XPaths are not possible and there are also hybrid variants. But are dynamic Xpaths because of "choosePerson" necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for any dynamic xpath here....

You could have the position passed in as a parameter to the template that matches `person`, along with the name of a child node you want to exlude

```
<xsl:template match="//root/person">
  <xsl:param name="position" select="position()" />
  <xsl:param name="excludeChild" />
```

So, for your first part, you would define a variable with the position of the person you wish to choose, and then apply the template to that person, passing in the variable as a parameter

```
<xsl:variable name="choose" select="substring-after(root/choosePerson, ': ')" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="root/person[position()=$choose]">
  <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$choose" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

For the second part, you can use the default position, but pass in the parameter to exclude the "birth" element

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="root/person">
  <xsl:with-param name="excludeChild" select="'birth'" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Try this XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <firstPart>
      <xsl:variable name="choose" select="substring-after(root/choosePerson, ': ')" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/person[position()=$choose]">
        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$choose" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </firstPart>
    <secondPart>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/person">
        <xsl:with-param name="excludeChild" select="'birth'" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </secondPart>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//root/person">
    <xsl:param name="position" select="position()" />
    <xsl:param name="excludeChild" />
    <person id="{$position}" gender="{gender}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name() != $excludeChild]" />
    </person>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="gender" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```